# Is this the proper use of imbued?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing lyrics to a song, and the first two lines I have written read as follows:

> The spiral begins as these thoughts are imbued,
> "I'm hideous sin and I have no value."

The idea I want to convey is the negative thoughts that saturate or permeate a person causes a downward spiral that can lead to despair.

Comment: You normally imbue something *with* something else, e.g. you imbue your mind with negative thoughts. But in lyrics you can take poetic license.

Comment: Not quite right. Those thoughts are imbued with self-loathing. Your mind is imbued with depressing thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

The word *imbue* is rarely used on its own without a *with*; [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/imbue-with?q=imbue) doesn't even list *imbue* on its own; they only define the phrasal verb *imbue with.* [MW does list](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imbue) some more obscure senses involving the use of *imbue* with just a direct object; it can mean "to tinge or dye deeply" or "to permeate or influence as if by dyeing." I think most would find your usage unidiomatic, but song lyrics need not strictly observe the rules of grammar.